# How do you restore an encrypted hard drive? Password being available

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, filesystem, encryption, luks

**Installed by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Installer:**

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop onto my notebook PC, and I made a wrong decision to alter the file ownership and permissions from the root drive as I wanted to access my notebook files via my desktop PC.

The result is that now I cannot access my disk.  My notebook has two hard drives, one flash boot flash drive enough for the system,  and a hard drive for storage which I made into to partitions, /Home and /Var.

**Below is a reference of commands with disk information output:**

## sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
 WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! 
 The util fdisk doesn't support GPT.  Use GNU Parted.

    Device  Boot      Start          End      Blocks    Id   System
 /dev/sda1   ?      6579571   1924427647  968924038+    70   DiskSecure Multi-Boot
 Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda2   ?   1953251627   3771827541  909287957+    43   Unknown
 Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda3   ?    225735265    225735274          5     72   Unknown
 Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda4   ?   2642411520   2642463490      25945      0   Empty

 Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

## sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda1

```
 Device /dev/sda1 is not a valid LUKS device.
 Command failed with code 22:  Device /dev/sda1 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

## sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda2

```
 Device /dev/sda1 is not a valid LUKS device.
 Command failed with code 22:  Device /dev/sda2 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

It seems that there's also /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4, but these partitions contain nothing and /sda3 has 5 blocks, /sda4 has 25945 blocks being empty.  This was all done via Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop installation.

**Section 1. Command Output**

## sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

```
 GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8 

 Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
 from backup! 

 Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out! 
 Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table 
 instead of main partition table! 

 Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk! 

 Partition table scan: 
 MBR: MBR only 
 BSD: not present 
 APM: not present 
 GPT: damaged 

 Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
 GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.) 
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

 Your answer: 2

 Disk /dev/sda:  1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
 Logical sector size  512 bytes
 Disk identifier  (GUID):  37C12505-96AB-4193-AD2F-A86ECEE7A8F9
 Partition table holds up to 128 entries
 First usable sector is 34, last uable sector is 1953525134
 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
 Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

 Number   Start (sector)   End (sector)  Size      Code   Name
   1              2048     1054685183   502.9 GiB  8300
   2        1054685184     1953523711   428.6 GiB  8300
```

**Section 2. Command Output**

## sudo lsblk

```
 NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM      SIZE   RO   TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
 sda       8:0     0    931.5G    0   disk
 |-sda1    8:1     0    811.6G    0   part
 |-sda2    8:2     0    346.1G    0   part
 sdb       8:16    0     22.4G    0   disk
 |-sdb1    8:17    0      512M    0   part  /boot/efi
 |-sdb2    8:18    0       14G    0   part  /
 |-sdb3    8:19    0      7.8G    0   part  [SWAP]
```

## sudo parted -l

```
 Model:  ATA WDC  WD10JPVT-08A (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 412B/4096B
 Partition Table: loop

 Number    Start    End      Size    File system   Flags
  1         0.00B   1000GB   1000GB  ntfs

 Model: ATA LITEONIT  LSS-24L (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sdb: 24.0GB
 Sector size (logical/physical):  512B/512B
 Partition Table: gpt

 Number    Start    End      Size    File system  Name  Flags
  1        1049kB   538MB    537MB   fat32              boot
  2        538MB    15.6GB   15.1GB  ext4 
  3        15.6GB   8398MB   linux-swap(v1)

 Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
 has been opened read-only.
 Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
```

## sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
 Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 gb, 1000204886016 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/tracks, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

 This doesn't look like a partition table
 Probably you selected the wrong device.

    Device  Boot      Start          End      Blocks    Id   System
 /dev/sda1   ?      6579571   1924427647  968924038+    70   DiskSecure Multi-Boot
 Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda2   ?   1953251627   3771827541  909287957+    43   Unknown
 Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda3   ?    225735265    225735274          5     72   Unknown
 Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 /dev/sda4   ?   2642411520   2642463490      25945      0   Empty
```

*In this case (/dev/sdb) is my system boot drive, while (/dev/sda) is the storage hard drive in which I'm trying to remount, and it has been set as 'DiskSecure Multi-Boot' by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Installer.

Now, why is it that '#lsblk' shows differing sizes (even greater than the disk drive max size)?

My booting hard drive (/dev/sdb) is already set as the boot drive with GPT.
Do I still need a GPT partition on my non-booting hard drive?

Also how may I mount my storage drive with the two partitions if '#parted -l' is only able to see one partition that is spanning the whole drive as ntfs?

**Section 3. Command Output**

## sudo blkid /dev/sda

```
 /dev/sda: UUID="58DEF9CB30F761D5" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: `fdisk` is not a suitable tool for GPT-partitioned disks. Can you [replace](https://askubuntu.com/posts/530684/edit) its output with that of `gdisk -l`? It would also help to see, what `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda` has to say.

Comment: #sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, 
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: Welcome to AU by the way! You can [edit] your question to add or update new information.

Comment: #sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8
Caution:  invalid main GPT header, but valid backup;  regenerating main header from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match.  You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR:  MBR only
  BSD:  not present
  APM:  not present
  GPT:  damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT.  Which do you want to use?  (Using the GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)

Comment: 1  -  MBR
 2  -  GPT
 3  -  Create blank GPT
Your answer:

Comment: `/home` is **not** your user's home folder. The latter is usually located one level below that. `~` is a shortcut to it.

Comment: Just to be safe store the partition table backup in `~/Desktop/sda.sgdisk` and copy it from the desktop to a USB drive or similar.

Comment: Does it make a difference if my notebook's BIOS uses UEFI partition type for disks?   EDIT:  UEFI boot loader*

Comment: Yes, it does. The partition type is called GPT (compared to the old MBR) and I've been talking about it all along.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPT partition table is broken according to the output of `gdisk`. Please backup your partition table to a file on a working drive with:

```
sudo sgdisk --backup=/path/to/backup.sgdisk /dev/sda
```

You need to store it somewhere where you have write permissions like a USB drive or your home folder. If you're on a live system, you should also store the backup persistently on another internal or external drive, because a live system usually looses all alterations on shutdown.

You can then safely proceed to with option 2 of `gdisk`'s question about which partition table to use. It will likely restore the GPT backup and put everything back in working order. Then you can try to resolve the permission problem.

Comment: I have reinstalled a new Ubuntu 14.04 installation.  And created the same username and password.  Also, I still remember the password for the two encrypted partitions  How do you back up the partition table in this case?

Comment: Any data in (encrypted) file systems is irrelevant to the backup of the partition table. Do you have any other disks mounted on the system you use to repair the broken drive?

Comment: #sudo sgdisk --backup=table /dev/sda > /backup.sgdisk
bash:  /backup.sgdisk:  Permission denied

Comment: I do not have any other disks mounted.  As mentioned there are two drives in my notebook, one flash enough for the system and one for storage which I've encrypted, as /home and /var.

Comment: How may I proceed to backup the partition table?   The string thing is I used Ubuntu's built-in backup and when I went to retrieve my backup, I received all /home files,  but the /var folder was empty.  Is there a block on the /var folder that would prevent backup?

Comment: I have no idea how you backed up your files and I'm not talking about those either. My answer speaks of backing up the partition table, which is something entirely different from the backup of you files. The backup instructions are laid out in my answer.

Comment: Some things I've read also mention something about the /var folder having permission issues as well.  Must be system and applications both using this folder,  but it still should be able to be backed up.  My usage of this /var folder stored my personal PHP Wiki and related-resources and settings.

Comment: Let's please deal with the partition table first, because there's no way we can acccess the file system with the wrong file permissions before that.

Comment: Right, and my files are encrypted and behind a "DiskSecure" Multi-Boot partition,  by Ubuntu 14.04 installer.    At this moment, my attempt to backup my files using Ubuntu 'Backups' did not work.  And now my attempt to back up my partition table as you suggested before proceeding, does not work.

Comment: How did you try to back up the partition table? What was the error you encountered?

Comment: USING:
#sudo sgdisk --backup=table /dev/sda > /backup.sgdisk 
RESPONSE: 
bash: /backup.sgdisk: Permission denied –

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using SUDO command.  I should have permission to copy any where on the hard drive.   Also, in this case, I've tried both / and /home.

Comment: I have edited the main post with the output of the command to back up to /home directory.

Comment: You also miss the point that this is a "DiskSecure" Multi-Boot partition.  Are you sure gdisk is able to manage a DiskSecure type?

Comment: “DiskSecure“ is a partition type and a level below partition **table** type (like GPT). `sgdisk` doesn't care about that for partition table backups. It just dumps the information.

Comment: I have updated my post above with the command output. And notice that parted -l shows only one partition for the whole storage drive, while lsblk shows two partitions and fdisk -l /dev/sda is even worse by showing 4.

Comment: `fdisk` is not suited for GPT partition tables. At least the partition table looks fixed now. I have no idea, how `lsblk` calculates the size or why `parted` thinks there's exactly one NTFS-formatted partition or the logical block size is 412B. The only plausible info seems to come from `gdisk`, which is specially tailored towards GPT partition tables. You should now be able to mount the two partitions through whatever means you would normally use.

Comment: Alright, so how should I mount the drive?  '#gdisk -l /dev/sda' shows that there are two partitions, but doesn't give the type.  And when I go to mount the partition, it's asking for the type.  Also, how can I add the partition when it's encrypted?   What about the "DiskSecure" layer?

Comment: I think this is getting to be more complicated that it really is.  The partition is mountable for /dev/sda1  but not /dev/sda2.   And strangely when I go to mount /dev/sda1, I'm able to see only one folder.   I cannot mount /dev/sda2 as even parted -l is not able to tell the filesystem type.

Comment: I mean fdisk sees /dev/sda1 as "DiskSecure" type,  and sees /dev/sda2 as 'Unknown' type.

Comment: Is there some type of "DiskSecure" partition manager?  Or a means to mount this type?  It is definitely not being recognized in either of these commands made above.

Comment: The partition manager really doesn't care about partition type flags. Furthermore there's no partition type for DiskSecure in GPT and frankly I don't even find any info what DiskSecure is supposed to be.

Comment: What does `sudo blkid /dev/sda?` say? If it's unable to determine the type of the partition content, then I don't know either what you put on there and how to retrieve it.

Comment: I've updated the post to contain the output to '#blkid /dev/sda', under Section 3. Command Output

Comment: That's nice, but nut very useful. I asked for `sudo blkid /dev/sda?`. Notice the question mark at the end.

Comment: Alright, so how do I revert back my partition table?  The fix of the partition table by your suggested '#gdisk -l > option 2' command.  I'd give you a negative rating if I were able to since you do not understand the issue, yet make suggestions.  It's a valid MBR,  not nut.

Comment: So far you have suggested me to list the partition information for you by '#sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda',  and the list has been provided with the GPT partition option (choice number 2).

Comment: `fdisk` detected a GPT which it cannot handle and a seemingly broken MBR that doesn't fit your description of the partitions on the disk. `gdisk` detected a corrupt GPT table but a valid backup, which fits your description. A part from some implausible findings by other tools, most of the evidence suggests that `gdisk` is correct. We seem to have serious communications problems and you often provided more or less different info than I was looking/asking for. I still didn't find out what DiskSecure is aside from a number in the seemingly broken MBR.

Comment: As far as I can tell nothing you described here changed the partition table on sda, so you can keep looking for a solution. I made a mistake with the backup command though, so that should be worthless. The correct way is in the update to my answer.

Comment: Alright, but I did not alter the MBR in any way, so there should be a default way to retrieve the files that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installer setup.

Comment: Does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS have an implausible encryption set up all along, and that it was never meant to be able to retrieve files after encrypting the drive?   I have read other posting with the same "SecureDisk" issue, and they lost five years work,  that was five years ago.

Comment: Broken hard disk encryption method that is irreversible

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. All the disk encryption methods in Linux that are worth mentioning have no means of recovery without the correct key. If you loose it, you can try to brute-force guess it or kiss your data good bye.

Comment: I have the password for it, and no encryption key set.  So how about that?

Comment: Huh? What encryption scheme are you using? Where do you enter your password?

Comment: It was set up by the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installer, default setup.

Comment: Since there were two partitions on the drive I set to encrypt during the setup, I had to enter my password twice per login, so no keyfile used.

Comment: I don't know which encryption is offered during installation, but I'm familiar with both possible kinds. Can you please provide the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda?`, so I can see what you/I/we are dealing with here? I'm getting tired of being left guessing, when you proved yourself capable of providing such evidence in the past.

Comment: What are you talking about?  The output of 'sudo blkid /dev/sda' was posted two days ago.  It is in my originial posting.

Comment: Yes, but not the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda?`. Note the question mark at the end.

Comment: The output to 'sudo blkid /dev/sda?'  is blank, no output

Comment: Does that mean the kernel doesn't detect any partitions on sda? What's the return value of `blkid` in that case (`sudo blkid /dev/sda?; echo $?`)?

Comment: The output is: 2

Comment: Then the kernel doesn't detect the partitions because the partition table is broken. As I said before, you need to run `gdisk /dev/sda` and choose the option to restore the GPT from it's backup copy.

Comment: Did and done, and I've posted the output already.

Comment: I only see `gdisk -l …` which doesn't modify or fix the partition table. It's only for display.